# Strange type in c++

Tags: c++, types, reference, parameters

I have a method with the prototype:

```
 bool getAssignment(const Query& query, Assignment *&result);
```

I am a bit confused about the type of the second param (`Assignment *&result`) since I don't think I have seen something like that before. It is used like:

```
 Assignment *a;
 if (!getAssignment(query, a))
    return false;
```

Is it a reference to a pointer or the other way around ? or neither ? Any explanation is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, haven't seen something like that before...

Comment: C++ only, nobody really does it, ussually its done as a C style double pointers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a reference to a pointer. The idea is to be able to change the pointer. It's like any other type.

---

Detailed explanation and example:

```
void f( char* p )
{
    p = new char[ 100 ];
}
int main()
{
    char* p_main = NULL;
    f( p_main );
    return 0;
}
```

will not change `p_main` to point to the allocated char array (it's a definite memory leak). This is because you **copy** the pointer, it's passed by value (it's like passing an `int` by value; for example `void f( int x )` != `void f( int& x )` ) .

So, if you change `f`:

```
void f( char*& p )
```

now, this will pass `p_main` by reference and will change it. Thus, this is not a memory leak and after the execution of `f`, `p_main` will correctly point to the allocated memory.

---

P.S. The same can be done, by using double pointer (as, for example, `C` does not have references):

```
void f( char** p )
{
    *p = new char[ 100 ];
}
int main()
{
    char* p_main = NULL;
    f( &p_main );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, a reference isn't really just like any other type. References aren't 'objects' in the C++ object model the way pointers and `int`s and every other type is, they can't be accessed after initialization because there's no syntax to distinguish between accessing the reference and accessing the referenced object, they don't follow the 'declaration mimics use' syntax, there are special rules for deducing reference types, etc. References are special.

Answer (score 12):

For something like this, you basically read the declaration from right to left (or inside out).

In other words, you want to start from the name of the item being declared, then progress outward. In this case, progressing directly from the name to the type, we get:

[image]

Comment: To add on, [this site](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) is good if you want a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @chris: I'm not particularly fond of that explanation. He calls it the clockwise spiral rule, but "clockwise" has nothing to do with anything. It would work exactly the same way if you decided to go counter-clockwise instead. At best it's emphasizing something that's utterly irrelevant.

Comment: True, clockwise has no special meaning, but you have to choose something to remember it by. I've also heard of going right-left-right-left. I never had a problem understanding anything after reading it when I found it, so it worked its magic on me pretty well, regardless of which way you choose to remember it. Much better than per-part memorization at any rate.

Comment: clockwise because the clock starts at 12'oclock. Just to remind you that you take the first right hand element.

Comment: @Jimmy: and the first right and element would be at 3 o'clock, half- way between 12 and 6 (hmm...now there's an interesting question: "when is 3 halfway between 12 and 6?")